# Testing a REST API in Nancy

Tags: c#, automated-tests, nancy

I'm trying in vain to assert on a Json response from a Nancy endpoint.

Here's the module under test:

```
    public MyModule()
    {
        Get["/mypath", true] = async (parameters, ct) =>
        {
            ...

            return something.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
        };
    }
```

How do I write a test that verifies the contents of the dictionary in the response?

I've tried all kind of things, such as:

```
            var bootstrapper = new MyBootstrapper();
            var browser = new Browser(bootstrapper);

            var result = browser.Get("/mypath",
                with =>
                {
                    with.Accept(new MediaRange("application/json"));
                });

            Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, result.StatusCode, "Body: " + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result.Body.ToArray()));
            Assert.That(result.GetModel<IDictionary<string, string>>()[SOME_KEY], Is.EqualTo("expected value"));
```

I've tried with and without hte MediaRange, and have tried to understand where the dictionary can be found in the response, but can't seem to find it anywhere. `result.GetModel` doesn't seem to contain the resulting dictionary at all.

The only way I was able to see the result is by watching `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result.Body.ToArray())`. This gives the raw JSON. However:

1. Manually decoding a byte array is ugly,
2. I would rather prefer a JSON object, not a string. Is that possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary is within a body of response. You can use special methods from Nancy.Testing framework to deserialize body into specific format, such as  `DeserializeJson`:

```
// Replace dictionary type parameters with yours
var actualValue = result.Body.DeserializeJson<Dictionary<object, object>>();
```

More details about NancyFx testing in Marcus Hammarbergs blog: [Nancy.Testing - test-dialogues with Requests and Response](http://www.marcusoft.net/2013/01/NancyTesting3.html).

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look later!

Comment: What's the difference between the GetModel<T> and the DeserializeJson<T> extension methods?